# Capybara / Ruby - How interacting with chrome plugins

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I'm trying to click on some chrome plugins to interact with it in my Capybara/Ruby/Rspec script. Is that possible? Or capybara scripts will just work in online interactions/urls.. Thanks!

Comment: To render web page `capybara` uses [`phantomjs.js`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) by default. So you need to make sure it uses [`headless chrome`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for that. And to research how to install plugins in headless chrome and interact with that if its possible

Comment: Nice, thanks for answer me.. do you have any examples?